# Centos 7 подвисает после команды reboot

Tags: linux, centos

После команд Reboot, init 6 и т.д. Centos либо показывает черный экран, либо пишет Rebooting и висит в этом состоянии. Сам перезагруз не происходит. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте из консоли выполнить команду из под root:

```
shutdown -r now
```

Comment: Не помогает... 
Помог вот такой способ:echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger 
Но после него дальше BIOS'a загрузка не идет.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема решилась отключением в BIOS опции Secure Boot